# How to run Python program installed system-wide through pip without root privileges?

Tags: permissions, python, pip

I have two different Ubuntu computers that both has multiple user accounts. I wanted to try the latest version of the backup program `Attic`, so I used `pip3` to install it—with success. However, I can’t run the program as a normal user.

If I do a local installation with `pip3 --user`, the program works as expected. But since I have multiple users, it would be too cumbersome to handle multiple local installations. I’d like to have *one* system-wide installation with normal users being able to run the program.

I’m guessing this is about permissions. How would one allow `pip3`-installed packages, that aren’t local installations, to be used by regular users—i.e., without using sudo or the root account?

**Edit:**

It seems that I’ve made it work, although my solution feels very hacky, and <strike>I don’t know if it’ll</strike> it doesn’t survive a package update. I carefully examined the file path leading up to `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/attic` and used `chmod` for giving the “other” group appropriate permissions, since they had *none*! I also used `chmod` on the individual py-files, giving them `644`.

I’ll let the question be open since there surely must be another, better way.

---

One thing leads to another... I have apparently, some time ago, changed the default `UMASK` to `007`. I have no idea if that’s the cause of the issue at hand, but I think it *could* be. I don’t want to change the value back to find out, since I quite like the privacy the current value gives.

I think I’ll just write a shell script that sets the correct permissions for all the `Attic` files (i.e. allowing “others” `r` and in some cases `x`), and then create an alias like `sudo pip3 install --upgrade Attic && sudo ~/.local/bin/fix-attic-permissions` in `~/.bashrc`.